# How to install CPAN modules on mageia 4

Tags: perl, cpan, mageia

How to install CPAN modules on mageia 4? I am struggling to find out to achieve this.

any help is appreciated..

Comment: Umm… any of the standard ways as per CPAN's documentation?

Comment: I tried the following ways `cpan install WWW::Mechanize` or `sudo cpan install MOJO::Dom` but nothing worked out.. It says CPAN is not found. It is driving me crazy ;((

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a basic Perl install yet.

Comment: Perl is installed (5.18.1). I tried with the command `perl -v`

Comment: Use [`cpanminus`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus): `curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus`

Comment: Have you tried using `yum` to install the modules that you require?

Answer (score 0):

First you probably don't need to, just install the package.

For example perl-WWW-Mechanize is the one for WWW::Mechanize.
You should use rpmdrake or urpmi to find the package providing the module you want.

```
$ urpmf --provides --literal 'perl(WWW::Mechanize)'
perl-WWW-Mechanize:perl(WWW::Mechanize)[== 1.730.0]
```

If you want to be able to use the cpan command, you need to install **perl-devel** package.